# Does GitHub flavored markdown, as rendered by kramdown have a maximum number of nested lists?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown

I am trying to render a markdown document with kramdown. The document has 4 levels of nested lists but the third and fourth levels are rendering as one list. Is there a limit to the number of nested lists in GitHub flavored markdown?

```
1. item 1

    * item 1.1
    * item 1.2

1. item 2

    * item 2.1

    1. item 2.1.1
    1. item 2.1.2

        * item 2.1.2.1
        * item 2.1.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Each level of indent should use the same number of spaces. For the subitems under `item 1` use appear to be using 4 spaces. However, for the first level of indent under `item 2` you only use 3 (rather than 4), for the second level of indent you are only using 5 (rather than 8), and for the third level you are using 8 (rather than 12). If you adjust your indentation, then you should not have any more issues.

```
1. item 1

    * item 1.1
    * item 1.2

1. item 2

    * item 2.1

        1. item 2.1.1
        1. item 2.1.2

            * item 2.1.2.1
            * item 2.1.2.2
```